# CORS not working in php slim framework

Tags: javascript, php, cors, slim

I have created rest api using php slim framework.
Here is my code

```
<?php
require 'Slim/Slim.php';
require '../lib/cors_enable.php';
require '../lib/logger.php';
require '../../db_config/config.php';
require '../lib/predis-0.8/lib/Predis/Autoloader.php';
Predis\Autoloader::register();
require '../lib/RedisMethods.php';
require '../lib/APICaller.php';
require '../lib/FosterGemOAuth.php';
require '../lib/FosterGemUser.php';
require '../lib/NewsFeed.php';
require '../lib/FosterGemBookmarks.php';
require '../lib/TopicWebsite.php';
require '../lib/FetchFullArticle.php';
require '../lib/PushNotification.php';


\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();
$app = new \Slim\Slim();

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
    // return only the headers and not the content
    // only allow CORS if we're doing a GET - i.e. no saving for now.
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD'])) {
        if($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET' || $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
            header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
            header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, X-authentication,Content-Type, X-client');
        }
    }
    exit;
}


$app->post('/messagebhej(/)(:profile_id/?)(:app_auth_token/?)', 'messagebhej');
$app->post('/login','login');


$app->run();

function messagebhej($profile_id, $app_auth_token){
    $error='';
    $request = file_get_contents('php://input');
    try {
        $request_data = json_decode($request,true);
        if($app_auth_token == APP_AUTH_TOKEN){
            $obj = new PushNotification();
            $res = $obj->sendMessage($profile_id, $request_data);
        } else {
            $error='Access Denied';
        }
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        $error=$ex->getMessage();
        log_error($error,"index.php | sendMessage function");
    }
    if($error) {
        $return_data= '{"Status":"Failed","Message":"'.$error.'"}';
    } else {
        $return_data='{"Status":"Success"}';
    }
    echo $return_data;
}

function login() {
    $error='';
    $request = file_get_contents('php://input');
   try {
    $request_data = json_decode($request,true);
    if(isset($request_data['EmailAddress']) && isset($request_data['Password'])){
        if($request_data['EmailAddress']){
            $obj = new FosterGemUser();
            $user_data = $obj->get_user($request_data['EmailAddress'],$request_data['Password'],$request);
        } else {
            $error='Please enter your email address.';
        }      
    } else {
        $error='Wrong Data Format.';
    }
   }  catch (Exception $ex) {
            $error=$ex->getMessage();
            log_error($error,"index.php | login function");
    }
        if($error) {
            $return_data= '{"Status":"Error","Message":"'.$error.'"}';
        } else {
           $return_data=$user_data;
        }
   echo $return_data;
}
```

Now both the api works fine when I call it using Rest client. However when I call login api from javascript it works well but messagebhej api gives error

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.fostergem.com/messagebhej/556714b04ec0a40d3cda0118/{app_auth_token}. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:63343' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.
```

I am getting crazy. Everything is is same then how the cors is enabled for one api and not for other.

Here is my cors_enable.php

```
<?php

// Specify domains from which requests are allowed
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

// Specify which request methods are allowed
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS');

// Additional headers which may be sent along with the CORS request
// The X-Requested-With header allows jQuery requests to go through
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With');

// Set the age to 1 day to improve speed/caching.
header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');

 ?>
```

Comment: Why someone downvoted the answer. Will it not better to explain the reason for downvoting?

Comment: Which server are you using? Apache?

Comment: Yes I am using apache

Comment: Tell me if [this](http://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html) could help you.

Comment: @NeelKamal have you found the solution yet. I have same problem but still don't know how to fix :(((

Answer (score 4):

There is no point of wrapping up header statements enabling CORS in your API with those conditions you have.

Right now it would set headers only if the REQUEST_METHOD is OPTIONS and HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD is either GET or POST, but your request wont comply to this.

So replace

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
    // return only the headers and not the content
    // only allow CORS if we're doing a GET - i.e. no saving for now.
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD'])) {
        if($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET' || $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
            header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
            header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, X-authentication,Content-Type, X-client');
        }
    }
    exit;
}
```

from your code with

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS');

header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With');
```

**PS:** Unless you have a server variable set as HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD, change it to REQUEST_METHOD

Comment: Thanks for the P.S.... had been searching to no avail...  Thought that was a new thing...

Comment: tried but didn't work. I had written those portion to handle pre-flight request.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue while working on an ionic hybrid mobile application. I added the following code below to my index.php file.

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*'); 
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers:X-Request-With');

header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With');
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but at the end I achieved to get it working

I am using cors-middleware https://github.com/tuupola/cors-middleware

These are my settings:

```
$app->add(new \Tuupola\Middleware\Cors([
    "origin" => ["*"],
    "methods" => ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE"],
    "headers.allow" => ["Accept", "Content-Type"],
    "headers.expose" => [],
    "credentials" => false,
    "cache" => 0,
    "logger" => $container['logger']
]));
```

Pay attention to the `headers.allow` key. If you try using `"*"` it will fail. You must enumerate at least these two headers as allowed.

Answer (score 1):

For Slim Framework 2.4 Version I did a small hack to tackle the Preflight OPTIONS request

```
\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();

$app = new \Slim\Slim();

if($app->request->isOptions()) {
   return true;
   break;
}

$app->post('/authenticate', 'authenticateUser');

$app->run();
```

So this will track all OPTIONS requests and return true and it worked for me.

My .htaccess file was like as follows

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Origin, Authorization"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, OPTIONS"
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up creating this simple middleware class:

```
<?php
class CorsMiddleware
{
private $router;

public function __construct(\Slim\Router $router)
{
    $this->router = $router;
}
/**
 * Cors middleware invokable class
 *
 * @param  \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface $request  PSR7 request
 * @param  \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface      $response PSR7 response
 * @param  callable                                 $next     Next middleware
 *
 * @return \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface
 */
public function __invoke($request, $response, $next)
{
    // https://www.html5rocks.com/static/images/cors_server_flowchart.png
    if ($request->isOptions()
          && $request->hasHeader('Origin')
          && $request->hasHeader('Access-Control-Request-Method')) {
        return $response
                      ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
                      ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*')
                      ->withHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", '*');
    } else {
        $response = $response
                      ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
                      ->withHeader('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', '*');
        return $next($request, $response);
    }
}
}
```

I use it like this (it's a string because of dependency-injection):

```
$app->add('CorsMiddleware');
```

Answer (score 0):

`$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']` looks wrong. That a valid _SERVER variable? You mean just `REQUEST_METHOD`?

Is the ORIGIN header in fact actually sent?  Trust the error message.

Can you use something like WireShark or at least step through your code somehow?  Even echo/log calls to make sure your logic is working as expected.

Comment: Login api is working as expected. But I am getting cross origin error only in messagebhej. I mean every configuration is same for both but still one is working while other is not. I am not able to figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

```
$app->options('/{routes:.+}', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    return $response;
});

$app->add(function ($req, $res, $next) {
    $response = $next($req, $res);
    return $response
            ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
            ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Accept, Origin, Content-Type, Authorization')
            ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS');
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Follow the instructions on the lazy CORS in the following link...this worked for me...

to be exact I made a cors.php file to serperate the routes you handle for cores and pasted all the code in the file.

http://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/cookbook/enable-cors.html

**UPDATE**

Since I faced this problem from my internal server where I had two web servers running for my back-end API and the other on Angular CLI the solution is in that context.

CORS operates by checking if the request url is valid by sending a preflight request using OPTIONS method, the problem is that your restful API router is not configured to handle that request so it gives a NOT_FOUND response. So what you do is add the routing for all OPTIONS requests as a simple solution, though you can be more specific.

To be nice and tidey, create a cors.php file where you will put the routes for your cors routes and add this code in it

```
<?php
//  Handling CORS with a simple lazy CORS
$app->options('/{routes:.+}', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    return $response;
});
$app->add(function ($req, $res, $next) {
    $response = $next($req, $res);
    return $response
        ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:4200')
        ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Origin, Authorization')
        ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS');
});

// Catch-all route to serve a 404 Not Found page if none of the routes match
// NOTE: make sure this route is defined last
$app->map(['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'PATCH'], '/{routes:.+}', function($req, $res) {
    // handle using the default Slim 
    $handler = $this->notFoundHandler;
    //page not found handler
    return $handler($req, $res);
});
```

Basically what this is saying is, for all options requests on all routes, just return a response without handling it. What's important here is the middleware which executes after returning the response, it sets the response headers that will tell your browser that it's OK to send the real request.

Note: Make sure that the cors.php file falls as the last set of routes. Also don't put an asterix as your domain origin, it doesn't work either.

Comment: Thanks @Zoe...I honestly put this up without the expectation of any readers because of how old it is.

Comment: Questions are bumped when anything (question or answer) is edited, or a new answer is posted. You've probably had more readers than you expect, although not everyone votes. I've removed my comment (and the flag got cleared before I had a chance to remove it). I'm not the downvoter by the way

Comment: Thanks for tips @Zoe and removing the comment, I actually got exited that someone voted and commented all in one go...I appreciate the feedback in it. Weird cause this code above worked for me just a few hours ago.